# Why is the else part of my code not triggering the reset function of the game?

Tags: java

I want the tic tac toe game to reset and show Draw if it's tied

But this doesn't seem to work.

```
package com.codewithmischief.tictactoe;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
boolean gameActive = true;
int activePlayer = 0;
int[] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};
int[][] winPosition={
                 {0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},
                 {0,3,6},{1,4,7},{6,7,8},
                 {0,4,8},{6,4,2}
                     };

public void tapBtn(View view) {
    ImageView img = (ImageView) view;

    int tappedImg = Integer.parseInt(img.getTag().toString());
    if(!gameActive){
        gameReset(view);
    }
    if(gameState[tappedImg] == 2) {
        gameState[tappedImg] = activePlayer;
        if (activePlayer == 0) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
            activePlayer = 1;
            TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
            status.setText("O's Turn");
        } else {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
            activePlayer = 0;
            TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
            status.setText("X's Turn");
        }
    }
        //check if someone has won
       for(int[] winPos : winPosition){

           if(gameState[winPos[0]]==gameState[winPos[1]]
                   && gameState[winPos[1]]==gameState[winPos[2]]
                   && gameState[winPos[0]]!=2)
           {
               String winner;
               gameActive=false;
               if(gameState[winPos[0]]==0){
                  winner = "X won";
               }
               else if(gameState[winPos[0]]==1){
                   winner = "O won";
               }
               else{
                   winner="draw"; //this one is not working also i want it to reset the game when draw.
               }
               TextView status=findViewById(R.id.status);
               status.setText(winner);

           }

       }
}


public void gameReset(View view) {
    gameActive = true;
    activePlayer = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<gameState.length;i++){
        gameState[i]=2;
    }
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView0)).setImageResource(0);
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(0);
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setImageResource(0);
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3)).setImageResource(0);
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4)).setImageResource(0);
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5)).setImageResource(0);
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6)).setImageResource(0);
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7)).setImageResource(0);
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView8)).setImageResource(0);
    TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
    status.setText("X's Turn");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Comment: What values can the elements of `gameState` have and what are you checking **before** that `if...else if...else`?

Comment: gameState is having the NULL values at start which is 2. and then later we will fill it with X=0 and O=1. the if else is checking if 1st element of winning postion is 0 (X) then it should be true for the other two values.

Comment: Is this for Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just inside the `for` loop, you check

```java
if (gameState[winPos[0]] == gameState[winPos[1]]
 && gameState[winPos[1]] == gameState[winPos[2]]
 && gameState[winPos[0]] != 2)
```

This means that somebody *must* have won: there are three of the same value in a row, and the value is not an empty tile.

When you then have your inner `if` statement:

```java
if (gameState[winPos[0]] == 0) {
    winner = "X won";
} else if (gameState[winPos[0]] == 1) {
    winner = "O won";
} els e{
    winner="draw"; //this one is not working also i want it to reset the game when draw.
}
```

Either X has won, or O has won, but *it cannot be a draw*, because the outer `if` statement has already determined that somebody has won.

To check for a draw, you just need to have the code exit the `for` loop without having set a winner, and then check that none of the tiles are empty.

**EDIT**: as requested, adding my suggestion as two code fragments.

First, replace the `for` loop with the following code. Notice that I pulled the `winner` string out of the loop and I added a `break` to exit the loop as soon as a winner is found. Similarly, I pulled the part that fetches and sets the label's text value out of the loop, so that it is not called for every iteration.

```java
String winner = null;
for (int[] winPos : winPosition) {
  // Did somebody win?
  if (gameState[winPos[0]] == gameState[winPos[1]]
      && gameState[winPos[1]] == gameState[winPos[2]]
      && gameState[winPos[0]] != 2) {
    gameActive = false;
    if (gameState[winPos[0]] == 0) {
      winner = "X won";
    } else if (gameState[winPos[0]] == 1) {
      winner = "O won";
    }
    // We found the winner, so exit the loop
    break;
  }
}
// If there is no winner yet, it might be a draw
if (winner == null && boardIsFull(gameState)) {
  winner = "draw";
}
// Only set the label text if there is a value to set
if (winner != null) {
  TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
  status.setText(winner);
}
```

You will then need an implementation of the `boardIsFull` method, which is relatively straightforward:

```java
private boolean boardIsFull(int[] gameState) {
  for (int i = 0; i < gameState.length; ++i) {
    if (gameState[i] == 2) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks billy but please can u do me a favour please add this in the whole code . i dont understand much like this sorry and thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
   for(int[] winPos : winPosition){

       if(gameState[winPos[0]]==gameState[winPos[1]]
               && gameState[winPos[1]]==gameState[winPos[2]]
/* A */        && gameState[winPos[0]]!=2)
       {
           String winner;
           gameActive=false;
           if(gameState[winPos[0]]==0){
              winner = "X won";
           }
           else if(gameState[winPos[0]]==1){
               winner = "O won";
           }
/* B */    else{
               winner="draw"; //this one is not working also i want it to reset the game when draw.
           }
           TextView status=findViewById(R.id.status);
           status.setText(winner);

       }
```

Line A means that the following code is only executed when `gameState[winPos[0]]` is not 2.

Line B however can only be reached if `gameState[winPos[0]]` is equal to 2, which cannot be due to the condition on line A.

Comment: so can i add else if(gameState[winPos[0]=2]){ winner = draw;} in the first if statement

Comment: @MayureshRaval No, to find if the game is a draw, you need to show that nobody can win. The simplest way is to see if the grid is full but there is no winner. If the grid is full, then there are no tiles with value 2. If there is no winner, then there are no three tiles in a row with the same value.